# changing ActionBar's height in orientation mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been using actionbar(android native)  for a few days(jellybean 4.2).
I tried to change the actionbar's height by adding such line in style.xml:

100dip

it works fine in landscapemode, but do not work in orientation mode.

in orientation mode, its height was not changed.

Comment: i suggest make a separate actionbar for landscape lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create dimensions for the height of the `ActionBar` in portrait and landscape mode:

**values/dimens.xml**:

```
<resources>
     <!-- dimension for the portrait ActionBar -->
     <dimen name="ab_height">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**values-land/dimens.xml**:

```
<resources>
     <!-- dimension for the landscape ActionBar -->
     <dimen name="ab_height">120dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Now you can use these dimensions like this:

```
<style [...]>
     <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/ab_height</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks. For there is not values-land directory in my project. So I create values-land direcory at same level with vlaues directory. and add the dimens.xml as you write, and change the styles.xml. but still it does not work in orientation mode. Did I miss sth?  and I omit sth, to actionbar: I just used tab in action bar. and using custom view on tab.