# How to change the height of action bar in android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to change the height of action bar ? I have tried with ActionBar.setCustomView(view, layoutparams) but couldn't change the height.
Please suggest.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15118422/826657 see this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690005/changing-actionbars-height-in-orientation-mode follow the link and do as suggested.

Comment: if u r use custom actionbar. set layout height to ?attr/actionBarSize                            like android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To set the height of ActionBar you can create a new file **themes.xml** in your `res/values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
    <style name="Theme.FixedSize" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

and set this Theme to your Activity:

android:theme="@style/Theme.FixedSize"

Answer (score 1):

Or just directly add the follow line inside the styles.xml:

```
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">35dp</item>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">35dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add
    item name="actionBarSize" 60dp item
inside styles.xml.