# Automatically Adjust Navigation Bar Height Based on Content with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am able to set the height of the navigation bar for the Android platform in Xamarin Forms using a couple of different techniques described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/navigationpage-bar-height) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670519/how-to-change-the-height-of-action-bar-in-android-4-2-2/45713836#45713836).

However, both of these methods set the height of the navigation bar statically. What I would like to do is to set the height based on the content. Specifically, I would like the height of the navigation bar to automatically adjust based on the TitleView content. I have observed that anything more than two lines in the TitleView get clipped by the default height of the navigation bar. I could set the height statically but in the cases where the is only one line of content in the TitleView there is too much padding.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to create a custom navigationBar? HeightRequest of Title and custom navigationBar  binding the same propertiese. Here is running gif.https://imgur.com/a/nGXBMLa

Comment: @leon-lu-MSFT - Can you point me to some documentation / code for this technique?

Comment: Just use `Stacklayout` to achieve it, Here is code screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/dl2k5Cb

Comment: @leon-lu-MSFT - Your solution is not what I am looking for. I want to be able to leverage the navigation bar that is provided by the `NavigationPage` type as this provides the navigation and navigation menu items out of the box

Comment: I found a only way to achieve it, use style.xml, but it cannot change the navigation bar dynamically.